# Unable to launch powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

The problem is this:

I have the installed powershell version 5.1 on Windows Server 2008 r2, and when I try to launch powershell.exe by `c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` or `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` paths, nothing happens.

But if I am moving powershell.exe to another directory on another drive (e:/ for example) and change its name to powershell_anyname.exe, then the console launches correctly.

I'm an administrator on this server.

Comment: have you looked at the even logs? this sounds like something AppLocker would do ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have looked AppLocker setting and logs, there is nothing

Comment: if copying & renaming makes things work ... then something in your system is set to lock down that exe file. i would talk to your admins and ask what changed ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Are you certain he shouldn't rather look at the odd logs? *\*scnr\**

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - i can't type - or proofread. [*grin*]